# Product rule proof for $f,g: U\subset\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've been struggling with that proposition but I don't know how to prove it.

Let $f: U\subset\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, $g: U\subset\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be functions that are differentiable on a point $a\in U$. Let $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$, with $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.Then $h: U\subset\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable on $a$ and

\begin{equation}
Dh(a)=g(a)Df(a)+f(a)Dg(a).
\end{equation}

Can anybody give me a hint or something? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(a+x)=f(a)+Df(a)\cdot x+o(x)$ and $g(a+x)=g(a)+Dg(a)\cdot x+ o(x)$ as $x\rightarrow0$, so that $fg(a+x)=f(a)g(a)+f(a)Dg(a)\cdot x+g(a)Df(a)\cdot x+o(x)$, or $$fg(a+x)=f(a)g(a)+\left(f(a)Dg(a)+g(a)Df(a)\right)\cdot x+o(x).$$

Comment: Hi! When you multiply the expressions for $f(a+x)$ and $g(a+x)$, where goes the $(Df(a) \cdot x) \cdot (Dg(a) \cdot x)$ term?

Comment: This term is $O\left(\|x\|^2\right)$ (and $o(x)$, in particular) as $x\rightarrow0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$
\lim_{k \to 0} \frac{\lvert h(a+k) - h(a) - Dh(a) k \rvert}{\lVert k \rVert} = 0
$$
and $f(a)g(a+k) - f(a)g(a+k) = 0$

**Spoiler:**

> $f(a+k)g(a+k) + f(a)g(a+k) - f(a)g(a+k) - f(a)g(a) = f(a) \left( g(a+k) - g(a) \right) + \left( f(a+k) - f(a) \right) g(a+k)$

Comment: I think it should be $\|k\|$ instead of $k$ in the denominator and under the limit.

Comment: @user2097 right, apologies

Comment: Hi! I understood it, but what happens with $\frac{Dh(a)k}{\lVert k \rVert}$?

Comment: @Abrahamlure I forgot the absolute values on the top - this should be the definition (or equivalent to the definition) of $Dh(a)$ that you use.